# Apple Watch: Can it be configured to only send outgoing calls?

Tags: apple-watch

I would like to configure an Apple Watch so that it can only send outgoing phone calls. The Watch would be for my elderly mother, so the ability to call for help (especially if the Watch detects a fall) is invaluable. Naturally, I do not want any inbound calls to go to the Apple Watch and bother the wearer, as it would be tied to my TMO cellular service.

1. Can the cellular Apple Watch be configured to only send outgoing
   calls?
2. Can the watch be configured to not "ring" when calls are received?
3. Can the watch be configured to not notify when SMS messages are received?

If you have a device and have configured it as said, please state this in your response.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the Apple Watch can be configured like this, but you might take a look at [Use Emergency SOS on your Apple Watch](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206983).